# How to vertically align a form in Bootstrap 4

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I have a form here inside of a container `div` and I wish to vertically align it in the page. I cannot for the life of me figure out how. I tried using tables and such and also flexboxes but I cannot get my head around it.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie-edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css" type="text/css">


  </head>

   <body>

    <div class="container">
       <div class="alert alert-warning alert dismissable fade show" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
           <strong>Note:</strong> This feature is not working yet. Don't try to log in!
        </div>
        <form class="form-signin  col-6 align-self-center">
            <h1 class="text-center">Sign In!</h1>
            <p>
                <label class="sr-only">Email Address</label>
                <input type="emai" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" required autofocus>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required autofocus>
            </p>

            <p class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label></p>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block ">Sign in</button>
        </form>

    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

</html>

And here is the CSS

    html, body {

    height: 100%;

}

.container {

    max-width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;


}

.form-signin {

    vertical-align: middle;
}

.box {

    border: 1px red dotted;
}
```

Comment: Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gkzhtknv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `height: 100%` to a div element does not stretch it to the entire screen. You can check this by adding some border to your div.
So changing the height value in your `.container` class to `100vh` should solve your issue.